# iphone app slow using phonegap

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, html, cordova

I have develop a iphone/android drawing functionality application using phonegap. On touch start and touch  move,  app can draw lines upon a canvas(Context).
Drawing on line is very slow.Even loading time of app is very slow.(The Splash screen display itself minimum 6-8 secs.

The size of www folder is less then 2MB. We are anot loading complex or heavy graphics.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You could give us more details about the app. Size (in kb), images loaded and so on. I noticed that Phonegap tend to be sluggish on complex/heavy graphic apps.

Comment: The size of www folder is less then 2MB. We are not loading complex or heavy graphics. The drawing functionality slow initially, but if user are using app continue then after some time app's draw functionality work fine to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this is what you mean, but to get it to draw in a usual manner, this is what your code should look like:

Note you can change the settings of your Context.

```
@synthesize canvas, drawing; //Both UIImageViews
CGPoint touchPrev;
CGPoint touchLoc;

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    touchPrev = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    touchLoc = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(canvas.frame.size);
    [canvas.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 8);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.8, 0, 0, 1);

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), touchLoc.x, touchLoc.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), touchPrev.x, touchPrev.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    canvas.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    touchPrev = touchLoc;
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    touchPrev = touchLoc;
}
```

Comment: Hi Fernando,  I am using html5/Javascript in my application(using phonegap framework). The above mentioned code is belong to Core Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation which is difficult to override. Doing this with web technologies bound to have this side effect. Only work around is to do this with 2D graphics.

Comment: Hi Rahul,
We are already using 2D Graphics.
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth-5;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight -5;             
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 35;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'WHITE';
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.lineJoin = "round";

canvas1.ontouchstart = function(e) {
// init x and y

}


canvas1.ontouchmove = function(e) {
// doing draw functionality

}

Comment: @neil, what you are using is javascript what I meant was QuartzCore or Core2D iOS frameworks

Comment: I am using html5 canvas/context to draw multiple line.The drawing functionality is very fast in iphone semulator, but slow on real device.

Comment: iPhone simulator is not real parameter of performance. Since it is running on Macbook (more RAM, more processor), it doesn't show real picture. I have created canvas based multiple apps using javascript, the performance is never same as compared to native frameworks due to WebView limitations. Interestingly the performance would be better if you create a webapp and open it in safari, as compare to UIWebView.

Comment: Our app would be web based coding and encapsulate in www folder.Phonegap allow to convert web app into native app. There are lot of phonegap app in the market with high speed performance. Why our drawing app is so slow?

Comment: @neil, PhoneGap display itself is although slow but not very bad. It is the intercepting user action touchstart, stop etc which makes it slow. Unlike native component, here the canvas is second level component inside UIWebView and hence transferring control and feedback will be slow as compared to drawing directly on the native views.